# what do i add to my htaccess file to prevent codeigniter router from routing requests to pages in a directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

what do I add to my htaccess file or "/application/controllers/Pages.php" file or "/application/config/routes.php" file to prevent CodeIgniter router from routing requests to pages in a directory eg (venus)
eg: I have CodeIgniter installed in "example.com"
I want "www.example.com/venus" works as though no code igniter is installed

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////
///application/config/routes.php file is:
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['venus/(:any)'] = "venus/$1";

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';


$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

////////////////////////////////////////
.htaccess file
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]

///////////////////////////////////////////////
///application/controllers/Pages.php file
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: MIKE
 * Date: 2/17/2019
 * Time: 9:46 AM
 */

class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function view($page = "home"){
       if($page = "venus/(:any)"){

        }
      else if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
}
```

But the issue is that www.example.com/venus/file1.php is still routing to my 404 page. This is the issue

Comment: Is it `/venus` or `/venus.php` that doesn't work? Or does both get picked up by CodeIgniter? And do you have a file called `venus.php` in the document root (where the index.php file is)? Please clarify what you want, what happens when you call what URL and show us the file structure (where the files are in the file system).

Comment: its "/venus/file1.php", "/venus/file2.php", "/venus/file3.php" etc . I have corrected it in the question body. Thanks pal

Comment: What happens if you access those files like: `http://www.example.com/venus/file1.php` and so on? The above htaccess rules should let you access files directly. It will only pass it through CodeIgniter if the file you're trying to access doesn't exist.

Comment: I get re-routed to the 404 page. and that the issue I need help with it

Comment: You can set different htaccess files per folder. Try adding a `.htaccess`-file in the `/venus`-folder that only contains `RewriteEngine Off` and see if that works better.

Comment: Yes... Thanks Pal. It worked like Magic. YOU ARE THE BOMB. Thanks Man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .htaccess file was created in the directory I did not want affected and had the text  RewriteEngine Off written in it